# How to change a column type in Database and JPA mapping correctly/most safely?

Tags: java, jpa, db2

I have the following hibernate field:

```java
@Column(name = MY_COLUMN)
public Long myColumn;
```

The `MY_COLUMN` column in a DB2 database is currently defined like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
  ADD MY_COLUMN BIGINT;
```

It turns out that this `MY_COLUMN` field should have been defined as a `DECIMAL(4,1)`, so I'll have to update that column accordingly in the DB and in the JPA field mapping.

What is the correct/most safe way to do this?

1. Update the DB first, then JPA mapping
2. Update the JPA mapping first, then the DB

*Please note: I can update the code for the JPA mapping right away, but to change the DB Column I'll need to have the DDL reviewed and executed by others, introducing some lag time.*

Things I'm wondering:

- If the JPA is updated first, will the code just be broken until the DB Column is Altered?
- Should I wait until the DB Column is updated before pushing the change for the JPA mapping to the remote repo?
- Is it just bound to be broken either way for some period before they are both changed?
- Does it depend on the datatypes involved?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Not using any DB Migration Tool. Just manually-executed DDL scripts to alter tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Flyway or an other DB Migration Tool?

The way to go is, IMO, alter the db with SQL, and after that, change the JPA entities.

If you use e.g. Flyway, you can combine this two steps and execute them automatically on the next startup of your application. Nothing is broken this way.

If you do not use a DB migration tool, you need to prepare your SQL statements, take down the application for the users only, release your new code with new entities and execute the SQL.
But I do not recommend this. If you do, create Backups.

Comment: So, without DB Migration Tools, if I understand correctly: alter DB column, this breaks the application (hence why you suggest to take the application down for users); then update the JPA entity, this fixes the issue introduced by the SQL change?

Comment: Exactly. Do not forget to make a Backup of the complete database before! If you run a web application, you can just redirect the URLs to a "this webapp is under maintenance now"-page.

Comment: What exactly is the concern which requires a complete backup of the DB? I don't think this is an issue in my case, I'm sure backups are already maintained; but are you suggesting that perhaps records could be lost if there exists a record in `MY_TABLE` whose `MY_COLUMN` value could not be converted to a `DECIMAL(4,1)`?

Comment: Yes. It depends on what column types you want to convert to other column types. There may be data loss because of the converting itself or because of the "style" of converting. Converting a small number into a big number is not a problem, but the other way will kill your data integrity. In this example, the old type and the new type have the same "Base?" - they are both numbers. But you might convert a varchar to a bigint in future, or (joking) a blob into a date. Maybe you need to execute several SQL statements for converting to a new type. I think you know what I mean. Be aware of that.

Comment: And for gods sake: Never run a SQL statement on a production database without testing the result on a test database. If there goes something wrong, you are lost. You must be 100% sure that your SQL is correct - and nobody is that sure. Do yourself a favour and make a backup before doing something like this. Invest some minutes to be on the bright side, and to never get in the situation where the production database ist messed up.